# Rights of ownership,

Tags: us3447950

Does the mere holding of the original document/certificate from the U.S.  patent office make you the owner of it? As in, like a stock certificate or U.S. bond left by elders to children not of the same name?

To put it another way ... say you found a u.s. patent, original document, would you then be the owner of said patent??

Comment: I believe the ribboned copy of a U.S. patent was a little like a deed is the distant past. Now it is just ink, paper, a coward stock cover and a ribbon. However, like real property, the patent office has a recordation dept. that holds records of who transferred what patent to who when. It is not a requirement to record a patent transaction so its information is incomplete.

Comment: Thank you sir. I am researching this for my friend old Bob. His father was the author of this patent, said not where he left inheritance for his son and i was hoping that this was it. bummer ....would have been nice for him. Thanx again for your time.

Comment: Oh - the patent in question is very old and expired decades ago - ownership is a non-issue once six months since the parent exeperation have passed. It has 0 value.